# Google Sheets appendRow and add values to specific columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed a sidebar form that appends values to an existing spreadsheet.

[image]

The form works; however, the new values are added starting at column A. I would like to adapt my code to select the columns to which appended values are inserted.  The backend code used to append data is:

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Recruitment_Contacts"); 
  ws.appendRow([rowData.LnRT,rowData.FnRT,rowData.Gn,rowData.St,rowData.Dtr,rowData.Trn,rowData.Td]); 
  return true;
}
```

The code used within HTML script to add data after the submit button is selected is:

```
 function afterButtonClicked(){
     var ln = document.getElementById("LnRT");
     var fn = document.getElementById("FnRT");
     var gn = document.getElementById("Gn");
     var st = document.getElementById("St");
     var dtr = document.getElementById("Dtr");
     var trn = document.getElementById("Trn");
     var td = document.getElementById("Td");

     var rowData = {LnRT: ln.value, FnRT: fn.value, Gn: gn.value, St: st.value, Dtr: dtr.value, Trn: trn.value, Td: td.value};

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData);

   }
```

Any support that the community can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So do you want to be able to move the columns and insert new columns etc.?

Comment: No.  Just insert values into existing columns.

Comment: Do you basically want to insert the values starting from the column of your choice, am I right? I.e you want ot be able to insert values from column C for example?

Comment: That is correct Mateo.

Comment: Below is a code revision the demonstrate what I am trying to do (note I have commented the columns to which I would like the items placed)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve my issue, I created a server side function called "recruitInfo" and listed all the columns in my worksheet.  I then called that function in my HTML code.  The video I used to walk me through this process is [Web App - Google Sheets CRUD, Part 5](https://youtu.be/pySGNhqopY4?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvM36efLpaHxbkZTGp2pfhx)

```js
function addRecruit(recruitInfo){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheetName");
  const uniqueIds = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var maxNum = 0;
  uniqueIds.forEach(r => {
                    maxNum = r[0] > maxNum ? r[0] : maxNum
                    });
  var newID = maxNum + 1;
  
  ws.appendRow([newID,
                recruitInfo.lastName,
                recruitInfo.firstName])
 }
```

```html
function addRecruit(){
       
       var recruitInfo = {};
            recruitInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            recruitInfo.lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){}).addRecruit(recruitInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this  is what you're looking for:

**Selecting content by id**

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("Recruitment_Contacts"); 
  const hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  idx={};
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){idx[i]=h;});
  ws.appendRow([rowData[idx[0]],rowData[idx[1]],rowData[idx[2]],rowData[idx[3]],rowData[idx[4]],rowData[idx[5]],rowData[idx[6]]]); 
  return true;
}
```

I do this a lot and I just hide the top row and it doesn't seem to bother anybody and warn them that if the screw it up I get to come and charge more for fixing it.

Comment: This code has been useful in helping me develop an array for "const hA"; however, I am not sure how to handle the forEach loop.  It looks correct and I am able to log it out; however the last line of code results in the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Last Name_RT' of undefined."  The good part about this error is that it is accessing the correct column.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the appending of a new row from the column index you want, you must use the Apps Script method [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) on the right range. Here is the code implementation with self explanatory comments to achieve this:

```js
// you can pass a column index to this function as a new parameter (or inside rowData)
function addNewRow(rowData,column) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Recruitment_Contacts");
  
   // Set as the data what we want to insert to then be able to know how many 
  // columns will this fill
  // We need to wrap the data into [] as it is expecting a nested array for [cols] and [rows] 
  var data = [[rowData.LnRT,rowData.FnRT,rowData.Gn,rowData.St,rowData.Dtr,rowData.Trn,rowData.Td]]; 
  
  // Set the values on the first row of the sheet (reproducing the behaviour of appendRow)
  // and starting from the row index you want (5 for example). 
  // It will be 1 row and the length of the data
  // long in terms of columns. 
  ws.insertRows(1,1);
  ws.getRange(1, column,1,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mateo.  Thanks for getting back to me.  Unfortunately the code you recommended did not work for me.  Where I am trying to map the data is presented below
                                                                         
ws.appendRow([
                rowData.LnRT,//insert to column 1
                rowData.FnRT,//insert to column 2
                rowData.Gn,//insert to column 3
                rowData.St,//insert to column 15
                rowData.Dtr,//insert to column 6
                rowData.Trn,//insert to column 8
                rowData.Td]);//insert to column 9

Comment: Hi ! So where do you exactly want to insert your new data coming in from the sidebar? **Maybe an image in your question showing the expected output could be helpful to clarify your intentions**. Do you want to insert each element you are inserting through the sidebar in a specific column index? **I have edited my answer as I forgot a little detail by the way, you might want to check it out again.**

Comment: Hi Mateo.  Thanks for the follow up.  I will give this a try.  Since my last correspondence, I have decided to rebuild my spreadsheet application.  I building out a CRUD functionality which may address my current challenge.  The support you have provided has been informative.  Thank you.